# How to return a pointer string from C Function

Tags: function, pointers, return-value, function-pointers, return-type

Someone pleae help me out with my this code... It prints (Null)
Please someone do also explain with an answer...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *findStringReverse(char *);

int main(){
   char str[50];

   printf("Enter a String\n");
   scanf("%s", str);
   if( strlen(str) > 10 )
   {
       printf("Invalid String.");
       return 0;
   }

   printf("Reverse of the String: %s\n",findStringReverse(str));

}

char *findStringReverse(char *str){
   int i,len;
   char rev[10];
   len = strlen(str);
   for(i=0;i<=len;i++)
      rev[i] = str[len-i-1];
   printf("%s\n",rev);         // Here it prints the reverse of the string.
   return rev;                 // But unable to return.
 }
```

So I am getting my output for the reverse string in the rev variable which is in the function below of the main code but I am unable to return the string stored in rev how can I do it ? In the main function when I print the value it shows (NULL).

The constraint given with the problem is that the rev value must be returned with char * way only.

Any help would be appreciated... ^_^

Comment: Your string `rev` is destroyed when the function finishes and the variable goes out of scope. Declare it in `main` and pass it with a pointer as you do with `str`.

Comment: Thank you bro... You are right the scope is limited. So is there anything else I can do without declaring the variable in main ?

Comment: The only way to return data from a function into the calling scope is to either declare the storage in the calling scope and pass pointers, or to `malloc()` space inside your function and return that pointer to the calling scope. However, if you use `malloc()` you need to be careful to `free()` any space you allocate.